# How can I count the number of posts from another user?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application I am using the Firebase Realtime Database and each user can make one or more posts. These posts are stored under `/posts` and each post contains a `userId` object.

How do I make a query to count the number of posts made by a particular user with [this database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTBXg.png)?

I am using Typescript & Angular 8.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. You already asked this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440268/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-user-from-collection-join-to-another-collection-fi

Comment: Hmm. Aside from the initial language barrier, it wasn't too hard to understand what they were asking. @PeterHaddad, would the answer below be best here or on the original question?

Comment: The original question is closed, you cannot answer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the user you wished to query had the ID `-LwSHv8HcYek347sEmXT`. You could search for posts using a [sorting and filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) by the post author using:

```js
let userId = '-LwSHv8HcYek347sEmXT';

let query = firebase.database.ref('posts').orderByChild('userId/key').equalTo(userId);

query.once('value')
  .then((querySnapshot: DataSnapshot) => {
    let postCount = querySnapshot.numChildren();

    // do something with postCount

    // do something with each post's data if you need
    querySnapshot.forEach((postSnapshot: DataSnapshot) => {

    });
  })
  .catch((err: any) => {
    console.log('Error counting posts: ', err);
  });
```

Comment: now It's working but the problem is how to append the variable postCount to html part

Comment: In it's simplest form, you could use `document.getElementById('postCountHolder').textContent(postCount);`. But because you are using angular, you can use a controller and a scope variable like `{{ postCount }}`. Search something like "change text in angular".

Comment: thanks ,,It's working